# Rails: ActiveSupport JSON parse ill-formatted JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The response I get is

```
page_play_model_exponentModel__getNum({"code":1,"message":"","result":{"icode":"JXdywDcV0hA","totalVv":6}})
```

This is not a typical JSON response. So when I use activesupport like

`decode_response =  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response)`, it will report

```
JSON::ParserError: 795: unexpected token at 'page_play_model_exponentModel__getN
um({"code":1,"message":"","result":{"icode":"JXdywDcV0hA","totalVv":6}})
'
```

How can I parse this properly? I want the `totalVv` value and I can get it ugly,
like

`totalVv = response.split("'totalVv':")[1].split("}")[0]`, but this is just weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a JSONP response, but you could use a regex to extract the JSON

```
response = 'page_play_model_exponentModel__getNum({"code":1,"message":"","result":{"icode":"JXdywDcV0hA","totalVv":6}})'
json = /(\{.*\})/.match().to_s
```